# How to change the defaultNavHost among a few already created fragments?

Tags: android, fragmentmanager, android-navigation-graph

I have a couple of fragments in my activity, each having their own `Navigation Graph`, they're created when the activity is created. What I want to know is how can I choose any of them to be the `defaultNavHost` or the `PrimaryNavigationFragment` after they are created?

The code below creates them and sets them as the default one, but I don't want to recreate them each time. How can I do that?

```
val finalHost = NavHostFragment.create(navigation)

supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.navFragment0, finalHost)
    .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(finalHost) // this is the equivalent to app:defaultNavHost="true"
    .commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find the code to do what I wanted, so here's my workaround:

**First** remove the `#setPrimaryNavigationFragment(finalHost)` from `fragmentManager`'s transaction in your Code, and/or remove `app:defaultNavHost="true"` from the `<fragment...>` in your XML.

**Then** create your `NavHostFragment`s and add each of them to a `HashMap`:

```
private val navHostFragments = HashMap<Int, NavHostFragment?>()

fun createNavHosts() {
    val finalHost: NavHostFragment =
            NavHostFragment.create(navigationId)
            .also { navHostFragments[aHandleToTheNavHost] = it }
}
```

**Finally** in `onBackPressed` get the `navController` of the proper navHost and navigate up on it:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (navHostFragments[aHandleToTheNavHost]?.navController?.navigateUp() == false)
        super.onBackPressed()
}
```

**Note:** when `#navigateUp()` returns `false`, it means there was nowhere to navigate up to. So in there you can finish the activity or anything else you may want to do.